# Error installing ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

thanks for your help and interest :)

λ npm install -g ionic
`C:\Users\Gueddou\AppData\Roaming\npm\ionic -> C:\Users\Gueddou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic`

> node-sass@3.4.2 install C:\Users\Gueddou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at `C:\Users\Gueddou\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-14\binding.node`

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7600

> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "ionic"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! node-sass@3.4.2 install: `node scripts/install.js`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@3.4.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node scripts/install.js
>
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sass
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gueddou\npm-debug.log

screen capture
[image: Screen Capture]